# Straight skeleton is a tree

Tags: trees, computational-geometry, polygons

Can anybody give me a hint on how to prove that the straight skeleton of every polygon is a tree. Here is the definition of the straight skeleton (taken from Wikipedia):

> The straight skeleton of a polygon is defined by a continuous
>   shrinking process in which the edges of the polygon are moved inwards
>   parallel to themselves at a constant speed. As the edges move in this
>   way, the vertices where pairs of edges meet also move, at speeds that
>   depend on the angle of the vertex. If one of these moving vertices
>   collides with a nonadjacent edge, the polygon is split in two by the
>   collision, and the process continues in each part. The straight
>   skeleton is the set of curves traced out by the moving vertices in
>   this process. In the illustration the top figure shows the shrinking
>   process and the middle figure depicts the straight skeleton in blue.

Here is an example:

[image: Straight skeleton shown in dashed lines.]

Comment: I recommend providing definitions of the objects in question; especially that of a 'straight skeleton'.

Comment: @QuinnCulver Would that do?

Comment: There might be something in Oswin Aichholzer and Franz Aurenhammer, Straight skeletons for general polygonal figures in the plane (117–126), which is in Computing and combinatorics, 
Proceedings of the 2nd Annual International Conference (COCOON '96) held in Hong Kong, June 17–19, 1996, Edited by Jin-Yi Cai and Chak Kuen Wong, Lecture Notes in Computer Science, 1090, Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1996, or in Aichholzer, O., Alberts, D., Aurenhammer, F., and Gartner, B. (1995), Straight skeletons of simple polygons, in Proc. 4th Internat. Symp. of LIESMARS, pages 114–124, Wuhan, P.R. China.

Answer (score 2):

It was first stated by Aichholzer et al. in *Straight Skeletons
of Simple Polygons*, 1995. A proof is given in my [thesis](https://www.sthu.org/research/publications/files/phdthesis.pdf), see Lemma 1.2.

The basic idea of the proof is: The simple polygon is tessellated into simply-connected cells that are connected with the boundary. If the skeleton would have a cycle then there would be a cell that is disconnected from the boundary.

**Generalizations.**

The statement is also true for positively weighted straight skeletons, as shown in Biedl et al., *[Weighted Straight Skeletons in the Plane](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/S0218195916600050)*, 2015. The paper also shows that the statement is no longer true if you allow negative weights.

From a topological point of view, one can show that the straight skeleton and its shape (like a polygon with holes) are homotopy-equivalent. That is, the number of (generator) cycles is the number of holes of the shape, see the figure below. So your question is a special case: no holes, no cycles.

[image: Homotopy equivalence]

Source: A [blog article](https://www.sthu.org/blog/14-skeleton-offset-topology/index.html) of mine.